# Problem setting up unit testing when using app engine patch on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

I'm having a lot of trouble writing unit tests for my app engine patch solution.

I've asked this question on experts exchange (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Python/Q_26509115.html) but it's been there for two weeks with no answer - hopefully the SO crew can improve on that!!

I've tried everything I've found on the internet, my current setup is using nose-aep, but I have also tried the standard unit test framework but it gives pretty much the same problem (the issue seems to be app engine patch, but it's not clear how to fix it).

Using the simplest test:

```
def test():

    #pass
    assert False
```

Both the pass and fail run as expected but I'm getting an exception shown which isn't affecting the outcome:

```
Exception exceptions.AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <bound method Signal._remove_receiver of <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x22da290>> ignored
```

As soon as I import the models, or any other file which references the models e.g.

```
from application.models import *
```

I get an error which suggests app engine patch isn't setting up correctly.  I've included the log output below.

Any help appreciated!!

**When using nose-aep the error is :**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5 /Applications/PyCharm-96.1063.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61552 --file /usr/local/bin/nosetests-script.py --with-gae --without-sandbox -w tests/
Connected to pydevd (version 1.1)
pydev debugger: warning: psyco not available for speedups (the debugger will still work correctly, but a bit slower)
pydev debugger: starting
nose.config: INFO: Set working dir to /Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/tests
Running on app-engine-patch 1.1
Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'User') ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'User')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.5.egg/nose/loader.py", line 382, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.5.egg/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.5.egg/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/tests/tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    from application.models import *
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/application/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ragendja.auth.hybrid_models import User
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/common/appenginepatch/ragendja/auth/hybrid_models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ragendja.auth.google_models import GoogleUserTraits
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/common/appenginepatch/ragendja/auth/google_models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ragendja.auth.models import EmailUserTraits
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/common/appenginepatch/ragendja/auth/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import *
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist/py_zipimport.py", line 213, in load_module
    exec code in mod.__dict__
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/common/zip-packages/django-1.1.zip/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 457, in <module>
    User = cache.app_models['auth']['user'] = module.User
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'User'
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
root: WARNING: Can't open zipfile /Users/craigedmunds/Documents/source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/common/zip-packages/.DS_Store: BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
root: INFO: zipimporter('/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/common/zip-packages/django-1.1.zip', '')
root: WARNING: Could not read datastore data from /var/folders/yb/yb1f3LPqE50UqVxSbqvYN++++TI/-Tmp-/django_reciply.datastore
root: WARNING: Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
root: WARNING: Could not read datastore data from /var/folders/yb/yb1f3LPqE50UqVxSbqvYN++++TI/-Tmp-/nosegae.datastore
root: WARNING: Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.102s

FAILED (errors=1)
Exception exceptions.AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <bound method Signal._remove_receiver of <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal object at 0x23da290>> ignored
```

**When using the standard python unit test framework:**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5 /Applications/PyCharm-97.8.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /Users/craigedmunds/Documents/source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/tests//
Testing started at 9:22 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm-97.8.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 58, in <module>
    modules = loadModulesFromFolderRec(a[0])
  File "/Applications/PyCharm-97.8.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 42, in loadModulesFromFolderRec
    os.path.walk(folder, walkModules, modules)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", line 290, in walk
    func(arg, top, names)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm-97.8.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 38, in walkModules
    modules.append(loadSource(os.path.join(dirname, name)))
  File "/Applications/PyCharm-97.8.app/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 31, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/tests//tests.py", line 6, in <module>
    from application.models import *
  File "/Users/craigedmunds/Documents/Source/reciply/webapplication/trunk/application/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ragendja.auth.hybrid_models import User
ImportError: No module named ragendja.auth.hybrid_models

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `nose-aep`.  We use `nosetests` with the google-app-engine plugin.  It was very easy to set up, basically by following the links provided at the bottom.  Sorry I can't help with your specific question using `nose-aep`.  Good luck.

Complete overview, including how to install:
http://www.cuberick.com/2008/11/unit-test-your-google-app-engine-models.html

Examples of use:
http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/

The GAE plugin for nose tests:
http://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/

Nosetest's plugin site, with documentation:
http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/